# UIpath Workflow Foundation .NET Framework

Tags: uipath

I've been exploring UIPath community edition and have come across that the Main window and most of its activities are just like a Visual Studio Workflow. Is it right to say that UIPath is built upon Workflow Foundation of .NET Framework? I'm just trying to reconcile them both in my head now.

Answer (score 6):

Yes that is correct. You can use many functions and methods within UiPath that come from .net. If you press crt+space when you are typing code you will get a list of all functions and methods available. You can even invoke code and execute previously saved Microsoft code.

Answer (score 1):

Not only it's build using Microsoft Workflow Foundation but you could also extend UiPath using Activities build in very similar fashion to WFF. So if you know how to create NativeActivity for example, you already know how to extend UiPath.
Note that the development in UiPath is not really code-extensive, knowledge of .NET is a plus but not mandatory.